# Are these knives safe?

Tags: food-safety, knives

I am wondering if these painted knives are safe to use.

[image]

Comment: Safe in what way? it  looks like a cheap knife.

Comment: I was referring to the paint/coloring.

Comment: Also: nasty to resharpen, since you will get abraded paint stuck in your sharpener/one your stone.

Comment: I have a couple of painted knives.  They were inexpensive, and came with a protective sheath. I specifically bought them to keep in a bin of stuff that I keep in my car of misc stuff that frequently come in handy (plastic utensils, serving stuff, plates, cups, bowls, straws, napkins, take out containers, birthday candles, etc). I had a no-name one where the handle broke off (unpainted) but the painted Kuhn Rikon ones have held up well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A knife that has a painted blade is best thought oof as a 'gimmicky' knife. There will be limited uses before sharpening starts to flake away the paint on the face of the blade.

The paint itself is pretty chemically non-reactive in most cases (it has to be to harden and stick to the metal).

There are some cases where paints may have harmful compounds. This would have to be evaluated by looking at condition of the knife and the paint adhesion. So, evaluate whether the blade itself is worth using, then keep an eye on it.

In essence, a knife like this is perhaps used under low stress conditions, or as a decorative piece, but any serious cook will not use it for long.

Comment: @Adam If it is a good strong blade, it can be usable. Just watch for signs of wear...

Comment: It depends - I have a few “painted blade” knives and so far no flaking whatsoever. And claiming unsafe ingredients in the paint sounds a bit like fear-mongering.

Comment: @Stephie Agreed. I was pushing a little there for max caution. I usually am on the other end of the spectrum... I'll edit.